# Passing values from an API through another API discord.js

Tags: axios, discord.js

So what trying to do is get some values I get from an API, pass onto an array to THEN pass it through another API and then add up the data it gets.
I already made this fetching it from 1 api, but I don't know how to fetch all the values from one api, pass it into an array, and fetch each value for each item.

```
let req1 = `https://inventory.roblox.com/v1/users/${imageURL}/assets/collectibles?sortOrder=Asc&limit=100`
               let req2 = `https://users.roblox.com/v1/users/${imageURL}`
               function getItems() {
                return axios.get(req1)
            }
            function getUser() {
                return axios.get(req2)
            }
            await Promise.all([getItems(), getUser(),getValue()])
            .then(function(response){
                let rap = response[0].data.data
                let items = response[0].data.data.assetId
                let itemarray = 0
                let value = response[2].data.items[items array goes here][4]
                 let sum = 0
                 for(let i = 0; i < rap.length; i++) {sum += response[0].data.data[i].recentAveragePrice}
```

this is what I have so far. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:
Heres what req1 spits out:

````
{
  "previousPageCursor": null,
  "nextPageCursor": "49034821991_1_a887f8ff3a6b076aafd71c91a5a4a4fb",
  "data": [
    {
      "userAssetId": 23726188,
      "serialNumber": null,
      "assetId": 7636350,
      "name": "Supa Fly Cap",
      "recentAveragePrice": 23535,
      "originalPrice": null,
      "assetStock": null,
      "buildersClubMembershipType": 0
    },
    {
      "userAssetId": 1329942875,
      "serialNumber": 13717,
      "assetId": 113325603,
      "name": "Recycled Cardboard Shades",
      "recentAveragePrice": 5703,
      "originalPrice": 25,
      "assetStock": 15000,
      "buildersClubMembershipType": 0
    },
    ```
req2 doesnt apply for this part of the code :p
````

Comment: `req2` result is in `response[1]`

Comment: that isnt the problem at all thats part of another code i already have solved